# Can't get radio values to send

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I am working on making a form that should take the three questions in the form and add them up. If the end value is equal to three it should open call another function called toggletab() when the submit button is clicked. I tried this with it telling me pass or false depending on the value but it won't work. I am not good at JavaScript and it is really confusing to me. It looks like it is running each question separately instead of waiting until the end and calculating them all together. I cannot figure out why this is happening. I also am not sure how to call another function that is in a separate file if someone would know how to do that.

Thank you. This is the HTML

```
<fieldset class="article">

      <legend>Have you had your record expunged before?</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="field1" value="0"  />
      <label>
        Yes
      </label>
      <input type="radio" name="field1" value="1" />
      <label>
        No
      </label>

  </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="article">
      <legend>Do you have any charges pending against you?</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="field2" value="0" onclick="getscores2(this)" />
      <label>
        Yes
      </label>
      <input type="radio" name="field2" value="1" onclick="getscores2(this)" />
      <label>
        No
      </label>
    </fieldset>

 <fieldset>
                <legend>Is your drivers license suspended?</legend>
                 <input type="radio" name="field3" value="0" onclick="getscores3(this)"/>
                <label>
                     Yes
                </label>
                 <input type="radio" name="field3" value="1" onclick="getscores3(this)"/>
                 <label>
                     No
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="submitbutton" class="article">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick='answer()' />
</fieldset>


</form>

<p id="totalScore">this is answer </p>

  <button onclick = "toggletab()" id="tabButton"><h3>first results</h3>
 </button>
       <form>
         <div id="first"  >
         <fieldset>
                <label>


  <fieldset class="article">

         <legend>Have you had your record expunged before?</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="field1" value="0"  />
      <label>
        Yes
      </label>
      <input type="radio" name="field1" value="1" />
      <label>
        No
      </label>

  </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="article">
      <legend>Do you have any charges pending against you?</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="field2" value="0" onclick="getscores2(this)" />
      <label>
        Yes
      </label>
      <input type="radio" name="field2" value="1" onclick="getscores2(this)" />
      <label>
        No
      </label>
    </fieldset>

 <fieldset>
                <legend>Is your drivers license suspended?</legend>
                 <input type="radio" name="field3" value="0" 
     onclick="getscores3(this)"/>
                <label>
                     Yes
                </label>
                 <input type="radio" name="field3" value="1" 
     onclick="getscores3(this)"/>
                 <label>
                     No
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="submitbutton" class="article">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick='answer()' />
</fieldset>


</form>

     <p id="totalScore">this is answer </p>

   <button onclick = "toggletab()" id="tabButton"><h3>first results</h3>
   </button>
       <form>
         <div id="first"  >
         <fieldset>
                <label>
                <legend>Is your arrest record a:</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="field4" value="1" 
    onclick="getscores4(this)"/>
                    IC 35-38-9-1
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="field4" value="2" 
    onclick="getscores4(this)"/>
                    IC 35-38-9-2
                </label>
                 <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="field4" value="3" 
   onclick="getscores4(this)"/>
                     IC 35-38-9-3
                </label>
                 <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="field4" value="4" 
  onclick="getscores4(this)"/>
                     IC 35-38-9-4
                </label>
                 <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="field4" value="5" 
      onclick="getscores4(this)"/>
                     IC 35-38-9-5
                </label>
            </fieldset>
```

This is the JavaScript

```
function getscores1(score1) {
var getscores1 = (score1.value);
sendScores(getscores1);
}

function getscores2(score2) {
var getscores2 = (score2.value);
sendScores(getscores2);
}

function getscores3(score3) {
var getscores3 = (score3.value);
sendScores(getscores3);
}
function sendScores(getscores1, getscores2, getscores3){
var total = getscores1 + getscores2 + getscores3;
answer(total);
}

function answer(total) {
if (total == 3) {
document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "false";
} else{
document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "pass";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables your functions are defining [are not global](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).  Their values disappear after the function returns.  So your sendScores function does not actually have access to those values unless you pass them as arguments.  But while `sendScores` takes 3 arguments, you are only sending one (the one you have access too when you call the function).

One option would be to store these as global variables, but global variables are Generally Evil™.  Alternatively, you can get all the values when you click submit.  Here is a working example.  Note this does not catch the case when the user does not respond to one or more of the questions.  Click the "run snippet" button below to see it in action.

For your final question, you can put your js in a separate file and then put `<script src="path/to/your/file/js"></script>` in your html to load it.

```js
function answer(total) {
  var score = 0;
  if (document.getElementById('exp_yes').checked) {
    score++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('chg_yes').checked) {
    score++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('sus_yes').checked) {
    score++;
  }
  if (score > 0) {
    document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "false";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "pass";
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="article">

  <legend>Have you had your record expunged before?</legend>
  <input id=exp_yes type="radio" name="field1" value="0" />
  <label>
        Yes
      </label>
  <input id=exp_no type="radio" name="field1" value="1" />
  <label>
        No
      </label>

</fieldset>

<fieldset class="article">
  <legend>Do you have any charges pending against you?</legend>
  <input id=chg_yes type="radio" name="field2" value="0" />
  <label>
        Yes
      </label>
  <input id=chg_no type="radio" name="field2" value="1" />
  <label>
        No
      </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Is your drivers license suspended?</legend>
  <input id=sus_yes type="radio" name="field3" value="0" />
  <label>
                   Yes
              </label>
  <input id=sus_no type="radio" name="field3" value="1" />
  <label>
                   No
              </label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="submitbutton" class="article">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick='answer()' />
</fieldset>


</form>

<p id="totalScore">this is answer </p>
```

Comment: Hello, This was really helpful and fixed the issue with the submit but, it only comes out to the right answer if all three are yes or all three are no. otherwise, it will write pass. Do you know why this would be?  Thank you.

Comment: @christiemattern i am not clear what you are asking.  What do you want it to do if some are yes and some are no?

Comment: If some are yes and some are no it should say "false". The only time it should say "pass" is if they are all no.

Comment: @christiemattern Then just do if score > 0 instead of if score === 3. Will edit shortly.